# Direct Model Substitute into a String, and provide example for documentation

Tags: swagger, springfox

We have a common object in our code that represents an Hexadecimal identifier (HexId).

On the wire it always go as the hex String, but internally we handle it as the HexId model.

We would like to document it correctly as a simple value with a proper Id as example.

I'm on Spring 5 with WebFlux and Spring Fox 3.0.0 (SNAPSHOT).

In theory we should do

```
.directModelSubstitute(HexId.class, String.class)
```

, but then documentation will provide as example the default String representation ("string"):

```
{
  "id": {
    "id": 1051000567000005
  }
}
```

Would it be possible to make this direct model substitute and provide the example to use every time the HexId is used?
I would like to have produced:

```
{
  "id": "1051000567000005"
}
```